# Using tkinter, when I place my tree and buttons on the canvas why do they disappear?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

below are my codes

when I place my tree and buttons on the root I can see them

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1500x900")
root.title("Writer")

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, borderwidth=10)
frame = tkinter.Frame(canvas)
vsb = tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor="nw")
frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))


def treeframe1(rows, df):
    tree["columns"] = list(range(1, len(df.columns) + 1))
    tree['show'] = 'headings'
    tree['height'] = '45'

    colnames = df.columns

    tree.column(1, width=90, anchor='c')
    tree.heading(1, text=colnames[0])

    for i in range(2, len(df.columns) + 1):
        tree.column(i, width=100, anchor='c')
        tree.heading(i, text=colnames[i - 1])

    for i in rows:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=i)


tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode='browse', height='45')
tree.place(x=960 + 200 + 00, y=45, width=920)
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
vsb.place(x=950 + 200 + 00, y=45, height=930)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=tree.xview)
vsb.place(x=960 + 200 + 00, y=970, width=960)
tree.configure(xscrollcommand=vsb.set)

b1 = Button(root, text="dd1", width=15)
b1.place(x=650 + 200, y=465 + 200 - 600 + 5)

b2 = Button(root, text="dd2", width=15)
b2.place(x=650 + 200, y=515 + 200 - 600 + 5)

b3 = Button(root, text="dd3", width=15,)
b3.place(x=650 + 200, y=565 + 200 - 600 + 5)

root.mainloop()
```

but when I place them on the canvas (i.e. replacing the "root" with "frame") i dont see them. Why is that happening?

I am new to tkinter so if someone to modify the code to make it work that would be really helpful

Comment: Heads up: you don't need both `import tkinter` and `from tkinter import *`. In this case, stick with `import tkinter` (though you'll usually see `import tkinter as tk` and classes prefixed with `tk.` a la `root = tk.Tk()`)

Comment: If all of the children of the Frame are managed by `.place()`, then the Frame would still have its default size of 1 x 1 pixel; it would be entirely your responsibility to give it an explicit `width=` and `height=` that will hold all of its children.  This is why it's generally recommended to use `.pack()` or `.grid()` instead, which will automatically resize the parent to fit the children.

Comment: You should make the `Frame` visible through `.pack()`, `.place()` or `.grid()`. @jasonharper's answer makes it clear that using `.place()` requires specifying the `width` and `height` of all of the material you hold in the `Frame`.

Comment: Why are you suing duplicate `vsb`?

Comment: Inline 42, change vsb to vsh for horizontal.

Comment: Why do you can want `Canvas`?

Comment: I can see all widgets. Actually, you missing frame.pack().   I used the "root" with "frame". BTW, I'm using .pack() for every widgets.

Comment: thank you all for the valuable comments, as I said new to tkinter (and not from tech background either). So all your comments are v valuable and deeply appreciate that fellas. @toyotaSupra thanks for correcting that. I have changed to ash. I wanted canvas as I have a lot of buttons and trees and entry widgets and I wanted something scrollable. So someone on SO recommended that I put a canvas on the root and make it work. Which it did, till I encountered these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `pack` or `grid` instead of `place` to add the Buttons.

```
b1 = Button(frame, text="dd1", width=15)
b1.pack(padx=(850, 0), pady=(50, 0))

b2 = Button(frame, text="dd2", width=15)
b2.pack(padx=(850, 0), pady=(50, 0))

b3 = Button(frame, text="dd3", width=15)
b3.pack(padx=(850, 0), pady=(50, 0))
```

You can use `padx` and `pady` to adjust the location of the buttons on the Frame. I added arbitrary values to make it a similar location to your `place` values.

Comment: The Frame is made visible via `canvas.create_window()`.  This change would make it not scrollable, which was the whole point of the code.

Comment: @jasonharper Ah, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that you haven't given the frame a size, so it defaults to being one pixel. You are then using `place` to put the buttons in the frame, and `place` won't cause the containing widget (`frame`) to resize to fit its children. So, the frame remains 1 pixel wide and 1 pixel tall.

You can easily see this by giving the frame an explicit width and height that is big enough to fill the space. For example, if you do `canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor="nw", width=1100, height=1100)` the buttons will appear.

Comment: Thanks again Bryan, some valuable tips! as I said all new to me so learning as I code!